# unexplained Session time out in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have Webform ASP.NET 4.5 application.

In the login page Session variable is set as :(simplified  related code)

```
 Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text; (txtUserName.Text cannot be empty)
```

and then

```
Response.Redirect("Survey.aspx");
```

In survey page I have

```
if (Session == null || Session["UserName"] == null)
    {
        string errorText = "Session was timed out due to inactivity, to  continue, please close All of your Browser windows and log in again";
```

In web.config file I have:

```
<system.web>    
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1200" />   
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"> </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Also on IIS itself I have

timeout   :02:00:00

[image]

Still users report Session time out intermittently, after 15-20 minutes.

What this cause this?

=============================

Update: After setting it up to stateserver I get:

```
Unable to make the session state request to the session state server. Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a remote machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.  If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the server name.
```

Comment: Look at the configuration of your application pool's recycling behavior.  It's probably configured to recycle periodically, which will cause InProc sessions to be lost.

Comment: I've also seen the Pool recycle from other process like an anti-virus scanning files.

Comment: If you set your session to StateServer rather that InProc the session information should survive pool recycling.

Comment: Check the idle timeout http://dirq.net/2012/06/speed-up-iis-application-boot-times/

Comment: @Joe, Very good point. It is set to idle time out minutes (20) Can this be the cause of this?

Comment: @SNash - yes it will cause InProc sessions to be lost every 20 minutes, so is the probable cause.

Comment: @ theduck another good point. So if I get it up to StateServer  I don't need to change the app pool setting?

Comment: Ok please provide these an an answer. What do you recommend change the app pool or <sessionState mode="StateServer "  ?

Comment: Make sure the `ASP.NET State Server` service is installed and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, your application pool is probably configured to recycle periodically, which will cause InProc sessions to be lost.

You also asked in comments:

> What do you recommend change the app pool or <sessionState mode="StateServer "> ?

In general, I would do neither!  Instead, I would design the application so that it is resilient to Session data being lost.

In your example, you're storing a username in Session.  Instead, I would use Forms Authentication, in which case the username will be available to you from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`: no need to store it in Session.

In general, I would only store stuff in Session that can easily be regenerated, e.g. by reading from a database.  To retrieve stuff from Session, check for null and regenerate if necessary, something like:

```
var mySessionValue = (MyType) Session["MyKey"];
if (mySessionValue == null)
{
    mySessionValue = ... regenerate value, e.g. by reading from database
    Session["MyKey"] = mySessionValue;
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. In IIS I see the WEbsite time out is set to 20 minutes. But under that website for my Survey Web application Session time out id set to 120. Does the second one override the first one?

Comment: @SNash - Since you're using InProc session, yes, it does "override" the first one.  The application pool will be recycled after 20 minutes, which will cause anything in memory to be lost, including Session, the ASP.NET Cache, static fields, ...

Comment: Very interesting. If i enable Formauthentication , how can I populate 'HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name'?

I remember I tried it once before and ''HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name'' was returning windows user. Not the person who was logged in my login form.

Comment: @SNash - it will return a windows user if you've enabled Windows authentication.  I'd suggest you read up on Forms Authentication, and post another question if you have any problems with it,  Here's a place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You may be losing the session state because the app pool is being recycled. There are all sorts of reasons why the app pool might get recycled including time-outs, exceptions etc.

If you change your session state from `InProc` to `StateServer` then your session information should survive the app pool being recycled.

There are some downsides to using `StateServer` - the primary one is that objects added to the session have to be serializable. This is not normally a big issue.

To make `StateServer` work you need to make sure the `ASP.NET State Server` is installed and the service is running.