# ASP.NET session not destroy as per Sesion.Timeout property

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, iis, iis-7

On users login I am setting Session.Timeout property and expecting session will expire as per timeout value if user is idle. I have set application pools Idle-timeout property to 480 on IIS. This works fine on my local machine but its not working on production server. I tried changing forms tag timeout value to 480 in web config but then if I set Session.Timeout to 5 mins then also session not expires after 5 mins. Why session timeout is not working on production?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unexplained Session time out in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512566/unexplained-session-time-out-in-asp-net)

Comment: @Kramb I have set app pools Process Model- Idle timeout to 480 and Recycling Regular Time interval 1740.

Comment: @Manoj Can you see if any requests are being made to the server? Could there be something on the page that pings the server and keeps the session alive?